# Can anybody help me with C# Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154(REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Tags: c, opc

I want to get data from LSIS OPC SERVER. LS Industrial provided the .dll and .cs library but I can register dll or cs library. I dont know why. Here is the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwgIy.png)

Even I change target platform to x85 or x64 or Any CPU, it still not work for me. I also tried register direct with system32 or system64, it also not work for me

Comment: Welcome to [so] please see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can register the dll with [regsvr32](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx). After that check with dcomcnfg if the dll is correctly registered.